# Long terminal output;time consuming code; no forethought

Tags: command-line, output

I am running a rather complex python script in Ubuntu 12.10 for the last seven days. It must have generated atleast 20k lines of output on the terminal till now but not all of it is visible.

I didn't have the foresight to enable unlimited scrolling on the terminal neither did I try something like saving the output to some file. But now I am running out of time and I just can't think of rerunning the entire code again and try such options.

Does anyone know how can I see the complete output now without having to rerun the script?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 8):

You can not. What goes outside the buffer is gone.

---

By the way... the smarter option would be to send that output to a logfile.

```
python script.py >/tmp/output.txt 2>&1
```

will send all output to `/tmp/output.txt`. If you open a 2nd TAB and do

```
tail -f /tmp/output.txt
```

you can see the log on screen and retain the information.

---

Also works:

```
python script.py | tee output.txt
```

or

```
python script.py 2>&1 | tee output.txt
```

Comment: To avoid the `tailf` step, you can also use the `tee` program: `python script.py | tee output.txt`. Note that some output might be logged to stderr instead of stdout. If you wish to retain this by merging it with the standard output, use `python script.py >output.txt 2>&1` or `python script.py 2>&1 | tee output.txt`. If is well-behaved, you can also pause execution of a program in bash by pressing Ctrl+Z. To resume execution, execute the `fg` command. Use the `bg` command to continue execution in the background.

Comment: @Lekensteyn thanks. I always forget about `tee` :P

Comment: another option: `script -a all_output.log` and then inside that script session run the program. Once the prog finishes, exit the `script` session with : `exit` (or Ctrl+d at the begining of the prompt). Then you can do show a page-per-page "replay" with: `more -v all_output.log`. Another (even better) option: use `screen`, turn on its log saving, and inside it start the program. `screen` has the benefit of allowing you to disconnect+reconnect to the session! (Ie, you detach from `screen` (`ctrl+A d`) and let it run the shell and prog in the server, and you can reconnect to it later)

Answer (score 2):

Open your terminal and go to `Profile Settings > Scrollbar` and there is an option to set it to unlimited. I don't know whether it would save all 20k lines. Or else try the solution from Rinzwind.